# Listbox control with centered text alignment?

Tags: c++, mfc

Having searched around a bit, I was not able to find anything on this matter. I would like to have the items in my listbox control (CListBox) to be center aligned, is this possible?

Comment: Could you please append some minimal code example to give us the chance to understand?

Comment: I have no code related to the item text alignment, and I haven't been able to find any on how to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is going to have to be to derive your own class from CListBox and override OnMeasureItem and OnDrawItem to draw the items centered as you want. You'll also have to make sure you create the listbox with a LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style.

Comment: I suppose I will have to look into that if that is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use LVCFMT_CENTER flag while inserting columns.

```
CListCtrl m_listctrl;
...
m_listctrl.InsertColumn(1, L"item_name", LVCFMT_CENTER, 40);
```

It doesn't, however, work for the first (inserted with index 0) column which 
You can insert empty colom
then delete it
after you insert all coloms

```
m_listctrl.DeleteColumn(0)
```